# Noneditable prop have bug with chevron cell

Tags: reactjs

When I put nonEditable: true my chevron cell is not working like no open close etc.

```
export const rows = (reorderable) => [
    {
        rowId: 1,
        height,
        reorderable,
        cells: [
            {
                type: "chevron",
                text: "",
                isExpanded: true,
                nonEditable: true,
            },
            { type: "text", text: "", nonEditable: true },
        ],
    },
    {
        rowId: 2,
        height,
        reorderable,
        cells: [
            {
                type: "chevron",
                text: "Children",
                isExpanded: true,
                parentId: 1,
                className: "text-gray-400",
                nonEditable: true,
            },
            {
                type: "text",
                text: "Children Content",
                className: "text-red-500",
            },
        ],
    },
];
```